# what does this one-liner JS do for 960.gs index page?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to adopt 960.gs (the 960 CSS Grid System) for my next HTML+AJAX project.

And it is best to get started by checking the implementation of 960.gs index page.

After inspecting the elements on this page I noticed the following one-liner in its head section:

Consider the following snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="...."></script>
<script>
this.top.location !== this.location && (this.top.location = this.location);
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="...." >
```

I am not a pro Javascript programmer, it looks weird to me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It makes sure that your site is not loaded in an `iframe`.

When you site is loaded in an `iframe`, `this.top` will refer to the outer `window`. The outer window's location is then compared to the location of the `iframe`, and the outer page is redirected to your site.

Comment: by taking advantage of the fact that a boolean expression will keep evaluating until it evaluates to false or ends.  It makes for terse code, but not necessarily very readable.